# sprintf function to print selected data in C?

Tags: c, printf

I want to use sprintf to group data and print it based on the different variables that constitutes the data. For example:

```
// This doesn't work but it is to show what I mean
char buf[20]; 
int x=335,y=10; 
sprintf(buf, "%d%d", x,y); 
printf("x = %s and y = %s",buf[0],buf[1]);
```

which would give me a garbage value when I try to print. What I need is not just to print but select from the buf the values needed e.g:

```
printf("x= %s ", buf[0]); //I want it to give me x = 335 and so on for the y
```

I already tried the above and it didn't work. Is there something that I can correct to make it work? If not, then are there other suggestions that I can use as a pointer to an array of data?

Comment: `I want to use sprintf to group data`...why? use a structure...

Comment: Please define "didn't work". What is your expected output?

Comment: Please post code that at least compiles. What is `b`?

Comment: Why don't you use a struct?

Comment: where `group data ` ?

Comment: My apologies I forgot to include the output

Comment: @SouravGhosh could you please illustrate an example to how it can be done with pointers?

Comment: You are concatenating the two values into a string. In that way you cannot do what you want. Use a structs or matrices to do it.

Comment: @AhmedAl-haddad you write you forgot to include the output. Well there is still no output in your question. Edit you question to clarify if you want an answer.

Comment: Using your ugly code:   `char buf[20]; 
 int x=335,y=10; 
        int start_of_y = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", x) + 1; 
 snprintf(&buf[start_of_y], sizeof(buf)-start_of_y, "%d", y);
 printf("x = %s and y = %s\n",buf,&buf[start_of_y]);`

Comment: Guys relax please haha! I am here to learn. Unfortunately I lost the output because I was running the code on a different machine. But thanks a lot for your input. I believe I will follow the answer that suggested using structures.

Comment: nevermind.. sometimes you may need to have multiple strings in same buffer... then you can have something like what you have done... but for storing multiple integers... a big no

Comment: In coding, sometimes there is an X-Y problem: "I want to do X and Y looks like a solution. How do I do Y?" when "How to do X?" should be the question.  With this post - as that looked challenging, I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35776136/2410359) how to do "Y" as that is what the OP asked.  Suggest OP _clearly_ define the X" problem with better than "other suggestions that I can use as a pointer to an array of data?".  After research, post a new question if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a struct, especially since you want to put the data in an array:

```
struct mydata {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int numelements = 10;
struct mydata *arr = malloc(sizeof(struct mydata) * numelements);
arr[0].x = 335;
arr[0].y = 10; 
arr[1].x = ...;
arr[1].y = ...;
...
for (i = 0; i < numelements; ++i)
    printf("arr[%d]: x = %d and y = %d",i,arr[i].x,arr[i].y); 
...
free(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `char array buf[20]`.

After sprintf buf[0] will contain 3 and buf[1] will contain 3  and buf[2] will contain 5 (all from 355). Then buf[3] will contain 1 and so on...

**Your code is ugly, you should not use single buf to store multiple int. Use structure instead.**

However, if you want this to work, you can try:

```
char buf[20]; 
int x=335,y=10; 
sprintf(buf, "%d\0%d", x,y); 
printf("x = %s and y = %s",&buf[0],&buf[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code needs to keep track of what portions of the buffer where used for each `int`

Use `"%n"` to record the offset of the print.
Use `"%.*s"` to limit the amount of a character array to print.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define INT_STR_SIZE ((CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)-1)*28/93 /*log10(2)*/ + 3 /*sign,round,nul*/)

int main(void) {
  char buf[INT_STR_SIZE * 2];
  int n;
  int x = rand();
  int y = rand();
  sprintf(buf, "%d%n%d", x, &n, y);
  puts(buf);
  printf("x = %.*s and y = %s", n, buf, &buf[n]);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
14817659331085377743
x = 1481765933 and y = 1085377743
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to do something like this:

```
char buf[32];
int x = 335, y = 10;
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "x = %d and y = %d", x, y);
puts(buf);
```

This prints:

```
x = 335 and y = 10
```

Of course, any time you immediately follow `snprintf()` with printing that string out to `stdout`, you could just use `printf()` to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I have added more details to explain what I needed help with in regards with the output. Please do check it out.